# Oxidized alkaline planets?

Tags: planets, chemistry

Obviously, it is possible to have a planet with an oxidizing and acidic surface environment--just look at Venus!

But is there a plausible natural way to get a planet with an oxidizing but alkaline surface environment?

The obvious way to get an alkaline environment is to give the planet lots of ammonia... but that's not really compatible with a highly oxidized surface!

Comment: Oxidiz**ing** and oxidiz**ed** are not synonyms. First the question speaks about *"an oxidizing but alkaline surface"*, and then it wants *"a highly oxidized surface"*. Which is it?

Comment: @AlexP I rather expect that a highly oxidizing surface environment will produce an oxidized surface. You don't get a lot of oxygen accumulation in the atmosphere (or sulfur trioxide in the case of Venus) until most of the stuff that it could oxidize is already oxidized.

Answer (score 3):

If my chemistry knowledge is not too rusty, I think it is not possible, based on the following considerations:

According to the theory of [Brønsted–Lowry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Br%C3%B8nsted%E2%80%93Lowry_acid%E2%80%93base_theory)

> In the Brønsted–Lowry theory acids and bases are defined by the way they react with each other, which allows for greater generality. [...] The acid, HA, can lose a proton to become its conjugate base, A−. The base, B, can accept a proton to become its conjugate acid, HB+.

In [redox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redox) chemistry

> - Oxidation is the loss of electrons or an increase in the oxidation state of an atom, an ion, or of certain atoms in a molecule.
> - Reduction is the gain of electrons or a decrease in the oxidation state of an atom, an ion, or of certain atoms in a molecule (a reduction in oxidation state).

Alkaline substances, based on the above, tend to act always as reducers, unless there are even more alkaline substances they react with, for example a weak base into a strong base, in which case the weak base would be oxidized.

Comment: Potassium hydroxide is a strong base but is stable in the presence of oxygen. That suggests to me that it should be *possible* to have a basic but also heavily oxidized and oxidizing environment; but specifically concentrating sufficient quantities of potassium at the surface feels implausible.

Answer (score 2):

## Lithium flats

Logan Kearsley suggested a good idea in a comment here - potassium hydroxide as an example of an alkaline compound that is fairly hard to oxidize.  (You can still do 2KOH -> 2K2O + H2, and oxidize the H2)

But suppose all a planet has to work with is lithium and oxygen.  Perhaps it arose shortly after the Big Bang, with [only hydrogen, helium, and lithium to work with](https://physics.info/nucleosynthesis/) ... and the hydrogen and helium were burned away by a bright star ... but it also received a large amount of water from an impact at some point, providing some oxygen.  Over time it has ended up as a sort of planetary "[lithium flats](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/lithium-flats-of-bolivia/)", of the sort that Bolivia [got couped](https://www.telesurenglish.net/news/elon-musk-confesses-to-lithium-coup-in-bolivia-20200725-0010.html) over.

Lithium flats are an example of alkali flats, just as lithium is an example of an alkali metal.  The *degree* of alkalinity need not be consistent with Earth, depending on the available materials, and especially because our alkali flats are neutralized with CO2 from the air (which forms carbonic acid in water).

Answer (score 1):

**Playa**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_lake

[image: playa]

> A dry lake bed, also known as a playa, is a basin or depression that
> formerly contained a standing surface water body, which disappeared
> when evaporation processes exceeded recharge. If the floor of a dry
> lake is covered by deposits of alkaline compounds, it is known as an
> alkali flat...

The alkaline salts comprising an alkali flat are oxidized.  Carbonates and borates are two examples.  In an alien environment with less water / CO2 you could oxidize carbonates further to calcium oxide which is seriously alkaline.

Answer (score 1):

From a chemical point of view you could have a large amount of [hypochlorite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypochlorite) ($ClO^-$) salts, for refference bleach is mostly sodium hypochlorite. They would be the salts of the weak acid hypochloric acid so would be alkaline and the hypochlorite ion is an oxidizing agent capable of oxidizing chloride ions to chlorine gas.

If you are wanting more oxidizing and slightly less alkaline, then you could also have a higher oxide, [Chlorites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorite), which are more oxidising but less alkaline.

To help the chemical stability, the environment would have to have a large amount of of oxygen and chlorine in the atmosphere.

hopefully that helps